# finding list of constant in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a list of constant:

```
FRUITS = [MANGO, BANANA, ORANGE, GUAVA]
```

and array which is superset of this constant, like

```
EDIBLE_ITEMS = [APPLE, CORN, MANGO, RICE, ORANGE, PAPAYA, LITCHI, RICE]
```

So now I need to test if any of the elements from FRUITS matches EDIBLE_ITEMS then call a function.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`Array#&`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-26):

```
FRUITS = ['MANGO', 'BANANA', 'ORANGE', 'GUAVA']
EDIBLE_ITEMS = ['APPLE', 'CORN', 'MANGO', 'RICE', 'ORANGE', 'PAPAYA', 'LITCHI', 'RICE']
(FRUITS & EDIBLE_ITEMS).any?
# => true
```

Comment: Thanks as we know we can do a problem in thousand ways in ruby so u have added one more

Answer (score 0):

Do as below using [`Enumerable#any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) :

```
EDIBLE_ITEMS = %w[APPLE, CORN, MANGO, RICE, ORANGE, PAPAYA, LITCHI, RICE]
FRUITS = %w[MANGO, BANANA, ORANGE, GUAVA]
FRUITS.any? { |item| EDIBLE_ITEMS.include? item } # => true
```